# Filter based on multiple criteria depending on when a certain condition is met?

Tags: javascript

The order should be as follows:

1. First check for most recent startDate
2. When startDate is similar, then use the most recent endDate
3. When startDate and endDate are similar, then the lowest item number.

Now the following code sample explains what these three scenario's should do individually:

```js
const resultA = (items) => items.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return prev.startDate < curr.startDate ? prev : curr;
});

const itemsA = [
  { item: 1, startDate: new Date(2021, 11, 4), endDate: new Date(2022, 11, 4) },
  { item: 2, startDate: new Date(2021, 0, 7), endDate: new Date(2022, 11, 4) }, // lowest startDate
  { item: 3, startDate: new Date(2021, 5, 4), endDate: new Date(2022, 11, 4) },
];

console.log(resultA(itemsA)); // // correct, is item: 2

const itemsB = [
  { item: 1, startDate: new Date(2021, 11, 4), endDate: new Date(2022, 11, 4) },
  { item: 2, startDate: new Date(2021, 0, 7), endDate: new Date(2022, 2, 4) }, // lowest endDate
  { item: 3, startDate: new Date(2021, 5, 4), endDate: new Date(2022, 3, 4) },
  { item: 4, startDate: new Date(2021, 0, 7), endDate: new Date(2022, 4, 4) },
];

const resultB = (items) => items.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return prev.endDate < curr.endDate ? prev : curr;
});
console.log(resultB(itemsB)); // correct, is item: 2


const itemsC = [
  { item: 1, startDate: new Date(2021, 11, 4), endDate: new Date(2022, 11, 4) }, // lowest item number
  { item: 2, startDate: new Date(2021, 0, 7), endDate: new Date(2022, 2, 4) },
  { item: 3, startDate: new Date(2021, 5, 4), endDate: new Date(2022, 3, 4) },
  { item: 4, startDate: new Date(2021, 0, 7), endDate: new Date(2022, 2, 4) },
];

const resultC = (items) => items.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return prev.item < curr.item ? prev : curr;
});
console.log(resultC(itemsC)); // correct, is item: 1
```

However, I was wondering if there was a way to combine these three so that it can be done in one function.

I was first considering something in the lines of:

```
const combinedFunction = (items) => items.reduce((prev, curr) => {
 return prev.startDate < curr.startDate || prev.endDate < curr.endDate || prev.item < curr.item ? prev : curr;
});

console.log(combinedFunction(itemsA)); // wrong, is item 1 but should be item 2
console.log(combinedFunction(itemsB)); // wrong, is item 1 but should be item 2
console.log(combinedFunction(itemsC)); // correct, is item 1
```

But this doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score -1):

The below snippet should work.

**Note:** For the itemsC, the expected result as per your rules should be item 2. Since the item 2 has lowest startDate compared to item 1 and lowest item number compared to item 4.

```js
const itemsA = [
  { item: 1, startDate: new Date(2021, 11, 4), endDate: new Date(2022, 11, 4) },
  { item: 2, startDate: new Date(2021, 0, 7), endDate: new Date(2022, 11, 4) }, // lowest startDate
  { item: 3, startDate: new Date(2021, 5, 4), endDate: new Date(2022, 11, 4) },
];

const itemsB = [
  { item: 1, startDate: new Date(2021, 11, 4), endDate: new Date(2022, 11, 4) },
  { item: 2, startDate: new Date(2021, 0, 7), endDate: new Date(2022, 2, 4) }, // lowest endDate
  { item: 3, startDate: new Date(2021, 5, 4), endDate: new Date(2022, 3, 4) },
  { item: 4, startDate: new Date(2021, 0, 7), endDate: new Date(2022, 4, 4) },
];

const itemsC = [
  { item: 1, startDate: new Date(2021, 11, 4), endDate: new Date(2022, 11, 4) }, // lowest item number
  { item: 2, startDate: new Date(2021, 0, 7), endDate: new Date(2022, 2, 4) },
  { item: 3, startDate: new Date(2021, 5, 4), endDate: new Date(2022, 3, 4) },
  { item: 4, startDate: new Date(2021, 0, 7), endDate: new Date(2022, 2, 4) },
];

const resultABC = (items) => items.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return prev.startDate < curr.startDate ? prev : prev.startDate.getTime() != curr.startDate.getTime() ?
    curr : prev.endDate < curr.endDate ? prev : prev.endDate.getTime() != curr.endDate.getTime() ?
    curr : prev.item < curr.item ? prev : curr; 
});

console.log(resultABC(itemsA));
console.log(resultABC(itemsB));
console.log(resultABC(itemsC));
```

Comment: Hi A K, welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you. Interesting answer. So what happens actually when you return 'prev', do you skip one iteration?

Comment: Maybe it works, however this code is totally unreadable, incomprehensible and unmaintainable. Please never use this in production

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: By returning 'prev', iteration won't be skipped. Only the other additional checks will be avoided.